# How do you lock the screen on suspend but not on hibernate when using lightdm's screen locker?

Tags: suspend, lightdm, hibernate, lock-screen

I want lightdm's screen lock to function on suspend but not hibernate, because I do not want to enter both a password to unlock the computer and the lightdm screen-lock password.  This question has been asked before, but the answer given no longer works.

Comment: Please provide additional details like your Ubuntu version.

Comment: The problem I see with lightdm's screen lock is that if you put it in a bash script, it will stop the bash script until a password is entered.  There isn't that problem with the screen locks of xscreensaver and gdm.

Comment: I am using Xubuntu 22.04 LTS.